# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean

Tags: spring-boot

I am upgrading from spring-boot from 1.4.4RELEASE to 1.5.12RELEASE. But during context loading I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 69 more
```

I have searched there were two ServletRegistrationBean in spring-boot.1.4.4

inflated: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean.class
 inflated: org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.class

but in spring-boot.1.5.12 there is only one class.
 inflated: org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletRegistrationBean.class

So mainly context package `ServletRegistrationBean` is missing and app is giving error while context loading.

Can somebody please help how to fix this?

Comment: That class has been removed (as explained in the changelog) it was deprecated in 1.4 and hence removed in 1.5.

Comment: I understand class has been removed. But this class (ServletRegistrationBean) bean is creating while loading app context. I am not sure how to avoid creating bean of this class while loading context. I am using pretty standard annotation. (SpringBootApplication
EnableCircuitBreaker
EnableHystrixDashboard
EnableHystrix)

Comment: The bean is being created because you have something in your code (or configuration) that is instantiating it and as you haven't followed the rules (using the non-deprecated version) it now fails.

Comment: Thanks for response @M.Denium, I shall try to figure it out.

Comment: I should add to that response that you also might be using an outdated dependency of a 3rd party library (and that it isn't your own code).

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down reason, why ServletBeanRegistration class being loaded.
1. In mine case, HystrixDashboadConfiguration class was trying to create a bean of ServletRegistrationBean and it didnt find corresponding class in spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.
2. when I commented EnableHystrixDashboard annotation from top of mine app class then it works.

Comment: Which basically boils down to have an outdated 3rd party dependency. In this case using an incompatible version of Spring Cloud.